# Alter table or select/copy to new table with new columns

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a huge BQ table with a complex schema (lots of repeated and record fields). Is there a way for me to add more columns to this table and/or create a select that would copy **the entire** table into a new one with the addition of one (or more) columns? It appears as if copying a table requires flattening of repeated columns (not good). I need an exact copy of the original table with some new columns.

I found a way to [Update Table Schema](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/tables#updateschema) but it looks rather limited as I can only seem to **add** *nullable* or *repeated* columns. I can't add *record* columns or remove anything.

If I were to modify my import JSON data (and schema) I could import anything. But my import data is huge and conveniently already in a denormalized gzipped JSON so changing that seems like a huge effort.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to use a query to copy the table, but don't want nested and repeated fields to be flattened, you can set the [`flattenResults` parameter](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/jobs#configuration.query.flattenResults) to false to preserve the structure of your output schema.

Comment: Can you give me an example please? I understand what you are saying but it appears as if I must flatten repeated columns (if there is more than one repeated) and this yields unsatisfactory results. So, is there a simple SQL way (web UI) to copy existing table to a new one with added columns.

Comment: Do you mean the "Cannot output multiple independently repeated fields at the same time." message?  That should go away if you flip the `flattenResults` flag to false.  You can try this in the web UI: `SELECT * FROM <table>`; click the "Show Options" button, select a destination table, turn "Allow Large Results" on, turn "Flatten Results" off.  This doesn't solve how to add new columns - but a join or union in the SQL query might solve that.

Comment: You were spot on! The only thing missing from your answer is that one must select a destination table. It won't work (UI will gray the options) unless the output is redirected to a table. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

I think you can add fields of *type* RECORD.

Nullable and repeated refer to field's *mode*, not type. So you can add a Nullable record or a Repeated record, but cannot add a Required record.

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/tables#resource

You are correct that you cannot delete anything.

Comment: You are probably right. I haven't tried it yet as I prefer a web UI solution. If that fails, I will certainly try this.